# How to run GitLab pipeline not in container?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

In GitLab pipeline I see that each stage runs in its own container. How can I run all stages/jobs in the same environment? I don't need any specific docker image at all, just runner environment is fine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the same "environment"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm using a lot of bash things besides variables and pass them from stage to stage is cumbersome. So, basically, I need the same instance of shell. Your answer is what is needed, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you self-host your runner, you can use the [shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) which executes your job scripts directly on the runner host without any container.

When using the `shell` executor, any `image:` key defined in any of your CI YAML files will just be ignored.